# c# AES decryption Hebrew letters display as question marks

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a string containing hebrew letters,
after enctyption when I'm tring to decrypt the encrypted string, all the hebrew letters are shown as question marks (like -> ??? ?? ??????)

those are the 2 methods I'm using to encrypt and decrypt

```
 public static string Encrypt(string dectypted)
    {
        byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dectypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider encdec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        encdec.BlockSize = 128;
        encdec.KeySize = 256;
        encdec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        encdec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        encdec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        encdec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform icrypt = encdec.CreateEncryptor(encdec.Key, encdec.IV);

        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(enc) + Key;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string enctypted)
    {
        byte[] encbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(enctypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider encdec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        encdec.BlockSize = 128;
        encdec.KeySize = 256;
        encdec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        encdec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        encdec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        encdec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform icrypt = encdec.CreateDecryptor(encdec.Key, encdec.IV);

        byte[] dec = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(encbytes, 0, encbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dec);
    }
```

can someone please tell me what is wrong and why I get question marks insted of hebrew letters?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use UTF8, not ASCII.

Comment: Note that the character codes in ASCII are only 7 bits (values 0-127).

Comment: Note that `Decrypt()` doesn't decrypt the output of `Encrypt()` because you have appended `Key` to the Base64 data, so it isn't valid Base64 anymore.  Also, as @AndrewMorton pointed out, ASCII only includes 7-bits so using it for the Key and IV will perform a narrowing conversion.  Maybe use Base64 for that too.

Comment: @Trevor yeah I know, I cut it back later on the program,
I just showed my code . and the problem was (as everyone mentioned) the ascii using, I changed to utf8 and it's working

Answer (score 7):

ASCII cannot represent Hebrew characters. It can only represent a limited set of Latin characters and symbols. UTF8 is probably the encoding that you want to use. Replace your use of `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` with `Encoding.UTF8`.